# Find all inexistent connections in graph

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, graph-theory

I have a pandas dataframe **Edges** with two columns **Node 1** |
**Node 2**

```
      Node1     Node2
 0      A         B
 1      C         B
 2      C         D
```

These basically show edges **(A,B) | (C,B) | (C,D)** in a graph

What i need to find out is Missing edges i.e not present **(A,D) | (B,D) | (A,C)**

Desired output

```
      Node1     Node2
 0      A         D
 1      A         C
 2      B         D
```

What i tried:

i converted DataFrame into networkx graph and then used nx.non_edges function for same purpose ( to find missing edges) 
but due to low hardware resources networkx fills up the RAM and notebook crashes .
I'm trying to find if it is possible through pandas Dataframe that i could get missing edges of graph or you can say i need to find COMPLEMENT of graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach could be as follows:

- Find all length `2` combinations of the nodes
- Iterate over them
- Keep the combinations not contained in `G.edges`

---

```
from itertools import combinations

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Node1', target='Node2')

edge_non_present = []
edges = set(G.edges())
for possible_edge in combinations(G.nodes(), r=2):
    if possible_edge not in edges:
        edge_non_present.append(possible_edge)

print(edge_non_present)
# [('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'D')]
```

---

**Update**

If this leads to a huge number of combinations, due to a high amount of nodes, take a slice of the returned generator, and only iterate on a subset of these:

```
from itertools import islice

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Node1', target='Node2')
n_comb = 100

edge_non_present = []
edges = set(G.edges())
for possible_edge in islice(combinations(G.nodes(), r=2), 0, n_comb):
    if possible_edge not in edges:
        edge_non_present.append(possible_edge)
```

Comment: I also tried using itertools but still notebook crashes.
Is there any way that i can only save few and leave other missing edges so notebook do not get crashed.

Comment: Thank you  ! this worked :) 
I was not aware with "isslice"
but this helped me alot